# Plot in Julia 1.3: functions of Plot not defined

Tags: plot, julia, scatter-plot

I'm trying to build a scatter plot in Julia 1.3 and found those example [there](http://julia.cookbook.tips/doku.php?id=plotting)

```
using Plots
scatter( 1:16, sqrt.(1:16), labels="Square Root", size=[600,240] )

ERROR: LoadError: UndefVarError: scatter not defined
Stacktrace:
 [1] top-level scope at /Users/...:19
 [2] include at ./boot.jl:328 [inlined]
 [3] include_relative(::Module, ::String) at ./loading.jl:1105
 [4] include(::Module, ::String) at ./Base.jl:31
 [5] include(::String) at ./client.jl:424
 [6] top-level scope at REPL[22]:1
in expression starting at /Users/...:19
```

I also tried an example from the official [Plot documentaiton](https://docs.juliaplots.org/latest/layouts/), but got a similar error message:

```
using Plots
l = @layout [  a{0.3w} [grid(3,3)
                         b{0.2h} ]]
plot(
    rand(10,11),
    layout = l, legend = false, seriestype = [:bar :scatter :path],
    title = ["($i)" for j = 1:1, i=1:11], titleloc = :right, titlefont = fo
)

ERROR: LoadError: UndefVarError: grid not defined
Stacktrace:
 [1] top-level scope at /Users/mymac/.julia/packages/Plots/2KhB2/src/layouts.jl:671
 [2] include at ./boot.jl:328 [inlined]
 [3] include_relative(::Module, ::String) at ./loading.jl:1105
 [4] include(::Module, ::String) at ./Base.jl:31
 [5] include(::String) at ./client.jl:424
 [6] top-level scope at REPL[22]:1
in expression starting at /Users/...:10
```

I tried to remove and re-install `Plots` with `using Pkg; Pkg.rm("Plots")` and `using Pkg; Pkg.add("Plots")`, but it didn't solve the problem

It seems that some of the functions of Plots are not defined/found by Julia

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What you are doing is correct. There must be some very weird issue with the code when it was downloaded. I would try potentially removing your Julia 1.3 project and manifest file and starting clean. It may also be worth trying to do a `rm Plots` `build` `resolve` `up` and such just to try and clean out any weirdness that is causing this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure why you are having that problem.  I am using the same version of Julia, and the first example worked for me.[image: scatterplot screen]

Have you added a backend? `using Pkg; Pkg.add("GR");` If not, do so.

You might try restarting your machine, perhaps it is in an odd state.
Open the Julia REPL and type

```
julia> using Plots
julia> names(Plots)[251]
```

You should see `:scatter`.  If you do, then try the scatter plot. If not, there is an issue with your configuration. Let us know in either case.

Comment: I restarted the computer and re-run the code, and it worked. `names(Plots)[251]` give s me indeed `:scatter`. I don't know what was the problem but it fixed. many thanks. Many thanks @JeffreySarnoff

Answer (score 1):

You may need to specify where the function came from:

```
using Plots

Plots.scatter(...)
```